# prestashop 1.7 set template .header footer not displaying

Tags: prestashop-1.7

Here is the controller code

```
 if($fortParams['Result'] == 'CAPTURED'){
        Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order-confirmation);    
    }else{
        $this->setTemplate('module:knetPayment/views/templates/front/confirm.tpl');

    }
```

tpl file code

```
<h2>your payment succeasdadss. </h2>
```

and output is only displaying message with no header footer leftcolumn

Comment: anyone please help me..!!!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I was migrating a module from 1.6 to 1.7. Finally, I solved the issue by modifying my .tpl file so that it includes {block ...} information. In your case, try modifying your .tpl content like this:

```
{extends file='page.tpl'}
{block name='page_content'}
<h2>your payment succeasdadss. </h2> 
{/block}
```

Apparently, it seems as if in 1.7 it is necessary to use some extra smarty tags

Comment: if my question is valid @javi you can Up it.